# ASP.NET WEB API do i need async client

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, async-await

I have a Web API application which exposes certain async methods, such as:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Put(string id){
  var data = await Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
  //do something to put data in db

return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Ok);
}
```

I also have a class library that consumes this API with System.Net.WebRequest like this:

```
   var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
   var response = await request.GetResponseAsync();
```

Does the response need to be retrievend async? If so, why? Or can I also use `request.GetResponse();`.

I used the `GetResponse` before which would sometimes throw a 500 error ( `An asynchronous module or handler completed while an asynchronous operation was still pending`). Once I changed it to `GetResponseAsync()`, I stopped receiving this error.

**EDIT: Code that sometimes throws a 500 error**

I had the web api method stripped down to (just to check whether the 500 error was business logic or something else). Note: this is after changing the consumer to async (first function is the consumer, then the api method):

```
    public HttpWebResponse(GetApiResponseForPut(string url, string putData, NameValueCollection headers)
    {
      var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

            request.CookieContainer = _cookieContainer;
            request.Method = "PUT";

            if (headers != null)
            {
                request.Headers.Add(headers);
            }

            var encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
            var byte1 = new byte[0];
            if (putData != null)
            {
                byte1 = encoding.GetBytes(putData);
            }

            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            request.ContentLength = byte1.Length;



            Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            requestStream.Write(byte1, 0, byte1.Length);

            requestStream.Close();
            var response = await request.GetResponseAsync();
            return (HttpWebResponse)response;

    }

    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Put(string id)
    {
      HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
      return response;
    }
```

Comment: *I used the GetResponse before which would sometimes throw a 500 error* Can you show us the code where that happened?

Comment: Where are you calling `GetResponse`? I only see `GetResponseAsync`.

Comment: Yes, this is after the change to Async as I put in the edit. It was request.GetResponse() before that

Comment: and `GetResponse` would return an error while `GetResponseAsync` doesn't?

Comment: Yes. Thanks for the answer/comments so far btw

Comment: Would you hit the server side when you called `GetResponse`?

Comment: Yes, it would hit and hit the return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK). However, then the var response = request.GetResponse() in the consumer would throw an exception

Comment: It has nothing to do with sync vs async or your question. Could you post a small, complete reproduce of your problem.

Comment: Yeah, I will see if I can make a small app to reproduce it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does the response need to be retrievend async? If so, why?

No, it doesn't. You need to separate how the server-side operates and how the client queries your endpoint. When you expose a method which is `async Task`, you state that in your server-side calls, you're making async calls. This is transparent to the caller, all he gets is an API endpoint, he doesn't have any knowledge of your internal implementation.

Remember, even if you use `async` on the server-side, the request will only return to the caller once complete.